# Is this "TRT - 6:31" flashed for one frame during the credits of "Planet of the Apes" original to any official release of the film?

Tags: credits, production-mistakes, planet-of-the-apes

I saw this "TRT - 6:31" appear during the end credits in a broadcast of *Planet of the Apes* I had DVRed.

[image: "Planet of the Apes" credits]

Is this original to any cut of the film? (Otherwise it was presumably added during some transfer step by the broadcasting station or whoever distributed it to them.)

(If you know what it is for, that would be even better, but if you can just verify that it does/doesn't appear in any original releases, that would be a satisfactory answer to my question.)

Comment: Just a wild guess but *TRT* could be the abbreviation for *Total RunTime*. Were there *6:31* worth of closing credits? It could be a signal to broadcasting stations that they can 'picture-in-picture' the next 06:31 and post their own station identification and promos in the surrounding letterbox border.

Comment: @Jeeped I'm not sure. Unfortunately, when I said "DVRed", I meant I used the Pause function to store it temporarily in the DVR memory and see it time-delayed by most of an hour, but after the program ended, the cable-company-provided DVR didn't let me save it more permanently to the storage, because once a program airing ends, if you then press the remote's Rec button, the box says something like "Cannot save to DVR a program that has already ended". (An irritating limitation--it's obviously in memory, after all, so it seems it should allow it.) So I can't check now, unless it airs again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in fact "Total Run Time" as defined by numerous internet sources. Foreign correspondent [Alasdair Baverstock](https://alasdairbaverstock.com/news/2018/12/19/tvvideo-industry-glossary#:%7E:text=TRT%3A%20acronym%20for%20%E2%80%9CTotal%20Run,piece%2C%20program%2C%20or%20show.) has a direct link to the definition.

In your example of "TRT 6:31", it is specific to the start of the end credits, and is a 'bookmark' for broadcasters to begin '[Picture-in-picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture-in-picture)', whether to show station identification, commercial advertisement, or to begin another program.

I did find a downloadable ['PBS Producer's Handbook'](https://bento.cdn.pbs.org/hostedbento-prod/filer_public/Producing%20for%20PBS/Handbook%20Drafts/PBS%20Producer%27s%20Handbook%20(December%202019).pdf) that does say in part "...the Producer must hold 30-seconds from the
final total running time (TRT) for PBS to insert a promo immediately following the end of the program body...

In your example the cue is at 6:31 and whether a control is manually or digitally activated is at the discretion of the broadcaster. And with the advent of DVR's and frame-by-frame technology the consumer is just beginning to see what normally they wouldn't have.